# imOnline.SomeOffline At the end of the session, at least one validator was found to be offline on Substrate Frontier NPOS blockchain

Tags: frontier-node-template, npos, pallet-imonline

I'm running the substrate frontier having NPOS consensus, facing an issue that stops producing the new blocks and stops at a specific block height.

Blockchain Explorer recent events:

```
imOnline.SomeOffline 
At the end of the session, at least one validator was found to be offline.
```

[image: Blockchain Explorer Recent Events Image]